# Linux, C: access() not catching permission problems, or something

Tags: c, linux, stat, opendir

I am writing a program to mimic some of the behavior of `find` that walks a directory tree and calls `lstat` on the files it finds there to determine their type.  The real `find` will ignore files where the user does not have R or X access in that directory.  I can't seem to replicate this behavior; my code will go ahead and make the `lstat` call and get an Illegal seek error (which is what I'm trying to prevent) even though the code that performs this is inside a block that checks `access()`.

My first thought was that perhaps the second `access()` call should be on the path and not path/filename, but that didn't seem to work either (and isn't it redundant anyway?)

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

My code (I'm cutting out error catching and other stuff for brevity):

```
    void open_dir( char *dir, char *pattern, char type )
    {
        DIR *d;
        struct dirent *de;

        if ( access(dir, (R_OK | X_OK)) == 0 )
        {
            d = opendir(dir);

            while( ( de = readdir(d) ) )
                examine_de( de, dir, pattern, type );

            closedir(d);
        }
    }

    void examine_de( struct dirent *de, char *dir, char *pattern, char type )
    {
        char fn[ _POSIX_PATH_MAX ];
        strcpy(fn, dir);
        strcat(fn, "/");
        strcat(fn, de->d_name);

        if ( access(fn, (R_OK | X_OK)) == 0 )
        {
            struct stat buf;
            lstat(fn, &buf);
            //check pattern matches, etc., printf fn if appropriate
            if ( ( S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode) ) &&
                 ( strcmp(de->d_name, ".") != 0 ) &&
                 ( strcmp(de->d_name, "..") != 0 ) )
                open_dir(fn, pattern, type);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lstat()` should *never* return `ESPIPE` (Illegal seek).  Are you sure it isn't another syscall that is returning that, or a unchanged `errno` value after a successful `lstat()`?  (In other words, the bug may actually be in your error-checking code that you've elided).

That said, there is no point in using `access()` in this way anyway - it just introduces a race condition (because the file permissions could change between the `access()` call and the `opendir()` / `lstat()` call), and doesn't gain anything.  Simply check the return value of `opendir()` and `lstat()` instead:

```
void open_dir( char *dir, char *pattern, char type )
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *de;

    if (d = opendir(dir))
    {
        while( ( de = readdir(d) ) )
            examine_de( de, dir, pattern, type );

        closedir(d);
    }
}

void examine_de( struct dirent *de, char *dir, char *pattern, char type )
{
    char fn[ _POSIX_PATH_MAX ];
    struct stat buf;

    strcpy(fn, dir);
    strcat(fn, "/");
    strcat(fn, de->d_name);

    if (lstat(fn, &buf) == 0)
    {
        //check pattern matches, etc., printf fn if appropriate
        if ( ( S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode) ) &&
             ( strcmp(de->d_name, ".") != 0 ) &&
             ( strcmp(de->d_name, "..") != 0 ) )
            open_dir(fn, pattern, type);
    }
    return;
}
```

This is generally the right pattern - rather than checking to see if the operation might work and then trying the operation, instead try the operation unconditionally and then check why it failed.

Comment: You probably thought it was an offhand comment, but I found that setting `errno = 0` after each `perror` made some difference, especially in the case of error checking on `readdir`, since `readdir` returns `NULL` at the end of the directory *and* in case of error, so my code was checking whether `errno == 0` before moving on.  But I will certainly also take to heart your warning about `access` -- thank you!

Comment: @SabrinaStar: You should set `errno = 0;` immediately *before* the `readdir()` call - the important point here is that unsuccessful calls set `errno`, but sucessful ones leave `errno` unchanged.